# Pegar o valor de uma tag <TD> por jquery e enviar para método em Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Como eu faço para pegar o valor de uma tag  quando eu dou um double clique nela e pegar esse valor e passar para um método na minha controller. A funcção double clique está funcionando.

```
$('#nmUsuario').on("dblclick", '.clique', function() {
    CarregaDados();
})
```

Onde nmUsuario é o tbody da minha table. O meu método `CarregaDados();`é onde eu quero pegar o valor da tag  clicada e passar para a controller via json.

```
function CarregaDados() {

    $('.rowid').find('td').each(function () {
        var test = $(this).text();
        alert(test);
    })


    $.ajax({

        url: '/CadastroAcesso/CarregaDadosPagina',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ aqui não sei o que passar }),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Alô, tudo bem?');
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    })
}
```

Onde rowid é a minha `<TR>`, porem, como eu quero pegar apenas a tag  clicada, faz sentido fazer um each? O código que eu fiz antes do ajax, não entra no alert. Não sei o valor de test.

```
public JsonResult CarregaDadosPagina(string _nivel, string _nome, string _usuario)
        {
            RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

            //var result_carrega_pagina = db.

            return Json(new {  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: O que o controller espera receber? Uma lista de string?

Comment: Vou editar e mostrar meu método controller. É um parâmetro string.

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar seu HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido por um outro colega:

```
$('#nmUsuario').on("dblclick", ".clique", function() {
   CarregaDados($(this).text());
});
function CarregaDados(ajaxParameter) {

     $.ajax({

        url: '/CadastroAcesso/CarregaDadosPagina',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
         data: { nome: ajaxParameter },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Alô, tudo bem?');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('Fail?');
        }
    })
}
```

### [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8bpe84a/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode saber qual td foi clicada utilizando "this" dentro da função de callback:

```
$('table td').on("dblclick", '.clique', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
})
```

Um outro exemplo com ajax:

```
$('table td').on("dblclick", '.clique', function() {
    var dados = {
        textoTd : $(this).text()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/CadastroAcesso/CarregaDadosPagina',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dados,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Alô, tudo bem?');
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    })
})
```